# Is this a common occurrence in TLOU2?

Tags: the-last-of-us-2

Near the start of the game, something happens gameplay wise, specifically;

> You switch to another character

Does this happen often and does it make up a significant part of the game?

I guess like most people, I just want to make sure that I’m getting more of the same, but different...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You play roughly half of the game as a different character. The two characters have different weapons and play in a bit of a different way, though the gameplay is very similar in general. The details are a bit of a story spoiler:

> The first half of the game you play as Ellie, and the second half of the game you play as Abby. There is also a kind of epilogue where you play as Ellie again.